# logging file NOT created in Eclipse-Java

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

I have written this piece of code just to check if I'm able to create .log file or not. Is the code correct or not?

```
package loggingLearn;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class Log4jExampleInJavaProgramming {

    public Log4jExampleInJavaProgramming() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("Inside constructor");
    }
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Log4jExampleInJavaProgramming.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside main");
        Log4jExampleInJavaProgramming lg = new Log4jExampleInJavaProgramming();

        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j2.properties");
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        logger.info("this is the info by log4j");
        logger.error("this is the error by log4j");
        System.out.println("After logger.info11");
    }

}
```

I created log4j2.properties file but its not creating .log file

```
==========================================================

# initialize root logger with level ERROR for stdout and fout
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

# set the log level for these components
#log4j.logger.com.endeca=INFO
#log4j.logger.com.endeca.itl.web.metrics=INFO

# add a ConsoleAppender to the logger stdout to write to the console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# use a simple message format


log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#log4j.appender.file=org.apache.RollingFileAppender
# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${E:\\eclipse-workspace\\log}/log4j2.debug
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log\\log4j2.debug


log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Comment: Why you define `log4j.appender.file.File` twice?

Comment: in `log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender` must file be lower case : `log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender`

Comment: Since the `log4j2.properties` file defines a console appender, why are you calling `BasicConfigurator.configure()`?? You should remove that line.

Comment: In the `log4j2.properties` file, why are you defining `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file`, then redefining it with `log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE`. Don't have duplicate entries. Clean up your file!